# Java: Run diskpart script and read output

Tags: java, cmd, command, output, line

I'm writing a java tool that needs to retrieve output returned by diskpart. Diskpart is called using the /s option with a specified script.  I'm using Windows 7 with the lowest possible UAC settings.

```java
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "diskpart", "/s", "c:\\dps.txt");      
Process p = builder.start();
p.waitFor();

InputStream ins = p.getInputStream();
System.out.println(ins.available()); // Output:  0
```

Using the following line instead of the above produces an empty output file c:\dps_out.txt

```java
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "diskpart", "/s", "c:\\dps.txt", ">>", "c:\\dps_out.txt" );
```

When calling diskpart using this method, there seems to be nothing to read from standard output, since Process.getInputStream() and the Windows output redirection both access standard output and fail to read data.

Calling diskpart directly requires elevation.

```java
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("diskpart", "/s", "c:\\dps", ">>", "c:\\dps_out" );
```

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "diskpart": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation.
```

How do I properly run the diskpart script and read its output from within the java tool?

Answer (score 0):

What is your question?

This is from DiskPart's manifest.

```
    <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
            level="requireAdministrator"
            uiAccess="false"
        />
    </requestedPrivileges>
```

Cmd doesn't require admin access so works (it's set `AsInvoker`). Calling DiskPart direct won't work due to the manifest - `requireAdministrator`.

Comment: How do I properly run the diskpart script and read its output from within the java tool?

Comment: Elevate to admin status. Diskpart won't run unless you are an admin. See `wmic partition get /format:CSV`. Wmic requires an admin to run it once on a machine, then any user can run it to do only what they are allowed to do, generally they can read anything.